# Not a unique table/alias stock:

Tags: php, sql

Ive got the query below :

```
$sql = "SELECT `scanners`.`KordNo`, `scanners`.`BundleNumber`
  FROM `scanners`, `TWOrder`, `Stock`
  INNER JOIN `TWORDER` ON `scanners`.`KordNo` = `TWOrder`.`KOrdNo`
  AND `scanners`.`Date` = '" . $date . "'
  INNER JOIN `Stock`  ON `TWOrder`.`Product` =`Stock`.`ProductCode`
  AND `Stock`.`ProductGroup` NOT BETWEEN 400 AND 650  
  AND `scanners`.`Scanner` IN (
  ORDER BY `scanners`.`KordNo` ASC";
  foreach($scanner as $x) 
  {$sql .= $x . ",";}
   $sql .= "0);";
  // And query the database
  $result = mysql_query($sql);
  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  $return[] = $row;
}
```

When i echo the sql on php my admin i get the error not a unique table/alias stock;

can someone advise?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [the other 40 questions](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22not+a+unique+table%2Falias%22) with the error "not a unique table/alias".

Comment: Is the table name really *Stock*?

Comment: that's how your query ends? `scanners`.`Scanner` IN (
  ORDER BY `scanners`.`KordNo` ASC" .. after IN you should have a subjuery or a list

Comment: Yeesh. Holy cargo-cult fieldname escaping, batman.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're using explicit JOINs, drop the other two tables off of the FROM clause.

```
...
FROM `scanners`
INNER JOIN `TWORDER` ON `scanners`.`KordNo` = `TWOrder`.`KOrdNo`
...
```

Answer (score 0):

On line 2 you have...

```
FROM `scanners`, `TWOrder`, `Stock`
```

Then you have some INNER JOINs on to TWOrder and Stock.

1. That's mixing syntax (`,` and `JOIN`) which is messy.  Stick to `JOIN`
2. It means that TWOrder and Stock are mentioned Twice in the query

If you REALLY need to include those table multiple times in one query, you need to give them alias names, so they can be distiguished from each other.

But I think it's probably a mistake and that Line 2 should just be

```
FROM `scanners`
```

Then, also, I'm not sure how you got that to compile. You have `IN (` and then an ORDER BY clause, to which you append a list of values.  You should append the list before the ORDER BY and then append the ORDER BY after you've finished the loop.